# Mx Record change from Amazon AWS Route 53 for Fastmail

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, mx-record

I wants to use Fast mail service for receiving all mails of my website but stuck in configuring the MX Record from Route 53.

I have added the MX record like this:

```
Name: mail.locate.ie.
Type: MX
Values: 
    10 in1-smtp.messagingengine.com 
    20 in2-smtp.messagingengine.com
```

When I'm testing for MX record I have found error saying:

> The domain you have tested (locate.ie) does not have MX records that point to our servers. The MX records we detected are: (none)

And also no MX record were showing from other online DNS Tools like MXlookup.

Please anybody tell me what I have not done correct to point the MX to FastMail Servers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you created the MX record under mail.locate.ie.  What this mean is that only mail destined for mail.locate.ie will work.  What you will need to do is create an MX record with the name field empty and put the same values in.